# How to find all classes that implement a specific interface using System.Reflection.Metadata

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to figure out whether I can reliably identify .NET assemblies that contain classes that implement a specific interface. The catch here is that I cannot load assemblies using Reflection because that requires resolving all references of the assembly to be loaded and that is just not possible in my situation.

This is why I attempt to do so using the NuGet package [System.Reflection.Metadata](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Metadata/) because that approach does not seem to require loading referenced assemblies. However, I'm stuck with completing the code so that the interface in question is found. Here's what I have:

```cs
namespace ReflectionMetadataTest
{
   using System;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Reflection.Metadata;
   using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;

   public static class Program
   {
      static int Main(string[] args)
      {
         if (args.Length < 1)
         {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Please specify a single file path.");
            return 1;
         }

         string filePath = new FileInfo(args[0]).FullName;

         using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
         {
            using (var peReader = new PEReader(fileStream))
            {
               if (!peReader.HasMetadata)
               {
                  return 2;
               }

               MetadataReader metadataReader = peReader.GetMetadataReader();

               foreach (var typeDefinitionHandle in metadataReader.TypeDefinitions)
               {
                  var typeDefinition = metadataReader.GetTypeDefinition(typeDefinitionHandle);
                  var interfaceHandles = typeDefinition.GetInterfaceImplementations();

                  foreach (var interfaceHandle in interfaceHandles)
                  {
                     var interfaceImplementation = metadataReader.GetInterfaceImplementation(interfaceHandle);
                     var whateverThatIs = interfaceImplementation.Interface;

                     // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                     // TODO: How would I find the fully qualified name of the the interface so that I can compare with the name I'm looking for?
                     // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                  }
               }

               return 0;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

How would I resolve `whateverThatIs` to an actual type of fully qualified name so that I can then compare it with the type/name of the interface that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, after a little more trial and error here is how I can find the fully qualified name that all classes within an assembly implement:

```cs
namespace ReflectionMetadataTest
{
   using System;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Reflection.Metadata;
   using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;

   public static class Program
   {
      static int Main(string[] args)
      {
         if (args.Length < 1)
         {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Please specify a single file path.");
            return 1;
         }

         string filePath = new FileInfo(args[0]).FullName;

         using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
         {
            using (var peReader = new PEReader(fileStream))
            {
               if (!peReader.HasMetadata)
               {
                  return 2;
               }

               MetadataReader metadataReader = peReader.GetMetadataReader();
               Console.WriteLine($"The file \"{filePath}\" {(metadataReader.IsAssembly ? "*is*" : "is *not*")} an assembly.");

               foreach (var typeDefinitionHandle in metadataReader.TypeDefinitions)
               {
                  var typeDefinition = metadataReader.GetTypeDefinition(typeDefinitionHandle);
                  var typeName = metadataReader.GetString(typeDefinition.Name);
                  Console.WriteLine(typeName);
                  var interfaceHandles = typeDefinition.GetInterfaceImplementations();

                  foreach (var interfaceHandle in interfaceHandles)
                  {
                     var interfaceImplementation = metadataReader.GetInterfaceImplementation(interfaceHandle);
                     var interfaceType = interfaceImplementation.Interface;

                     if (interfaceType.Kind == HandleKind.TypeReference)
                     {
                        var typeReferenceHandle = (TypeReferenceHandle)interfaceType;
                        var typeReference = metadataReader.GetTypeReference(typeReferenceHandle);
                        var namespaceName = metadataReader.GetString(typeReference.Namespace);
                        var interfaceName = metadataReader.GetString(typeReference.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine($"  Interface Name: {namespaceName}.{interfaceName}");
                     }
                  }
               }

               return 0;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```